# Que significa RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ ?path=$1 [QSA,L] en mi .htaccess

Tags: php, hosting, host

estoy creando una pagina web, pero al cambiar de pagina en pagina no funciona dentro del host, pero de forma local funciona perfectamente, estoy usando PHP con el framework MINI 3.

Estoy pensando que es el .htaccess, el cual lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
# Necessary to prevent problems when using a controller named "index" and having a root index.php
# more here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html
Options -MultiViews

# Activates URL rewriting (like myproject.com/controller/action/1/2/3)
RewriteEngine On

# Prevent people from looking directly into folders
Options -Indexes

# If the following conditions are true, then rewrite the URL:
# If the requested filename is not a directory,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# and if the requested filename is not a regular file that exists,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and if the requested filename is not a symbolic link,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# then rewrite the URL in the following way:
# Take the whole request filename and provide it as the value of a
# "url" query parameter to index.php. Append any query string from
# the original URL as further query parameters (QSA), and stop
# processing this .htaccess file (L).
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

En el propio fichero `.htaccess` ya se está explicando lo que hace cada línea.

- [**RewriteEngine**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine)

```
# Esto te permite hacer uso del módulo mod_rewrite 
# para poder reescribir o redireccionar URLs.
RewriteEngine On
```

- [**RewriteCond**:](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
# Si las siguientes condiciones son verdaderas, entonces redireccionamos la URL:
# Si el nombre de fichero solicitado no es un directorio,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Y además, si el nombre de fichero solicitado no es un archivo que 
# ya exista (podría existir a nivel de servidor lo que estés buscando por la URL)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Y el fichero solicitado no es un enlace simbólico 
# ¿Qué es un enlace simbólico? https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlace_simb%C3%B3lico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

- [**RewriteRule**:](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
# Entonces sobreescribe la URL de la siguiente forma:
# Coge todo el fichero solicitado y se convierte, por así decirlo
# a un parámetro de URL. Esto además añade cualquier texto
# de la URL original como parámetros adicionales [QSA]
# Con [L] lo que le indicas es que no siga leyendo más reglas 
# (en caso de que sigas teniendo reglas en el .htaccess).
# Ten en cuenta que (.+) es una expresión regular que, directamente
# Hace match con cualquier caracter que se ingrese.
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Esto quiere decir, que una URL de la siguiente forma:

```
https://es.stackoverflow.com/test.php
```

Quedaría así:

```
https://es.stackoverflow.com/index.php?url=test.php
```

Como ves, el fichero solicitado en la URL principal (test.php) está pasando a ser un parámetro de url.

Puedes probar las reglas RewriteRule en el siguiente enlace https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

---

Otra cosa, lo que ves al final de la redirección ([QSA]), son [flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html). Esto lo que hace es, por así decirlo, modificar el compartamiento de la redirección.

- [**QSA**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) : De una manera resumida, añade la cadena de la consulta a la URL que sustituye.
- [**L**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) : Este flag indica `last` o último. Lo que hace es para el procesamiento de las reglas. Por lo que si se cumplen todas las condiciones (RewriteCond), al llegar a esta regla de RewriteRule, se dejan de leer el resto de reglas.

Puede ser un poco complicado de entender al principio. Pero si lees con un poco más de detenimiento la documentación y practicas aplicando reglas por tu cuenta, además de comprender un mínimo de expresiones regulares, se te hará un poco más sencillo de entender.

Espero haber ayudado.